# Check if number is prime

Tags: pascal

Can anybody please help me out with making Pascal function to check if number is prime? Boolean function returning true or false would be most helpful as my program requires looping through more numbers, testing them out and outputting if they are indeed prime. This is the part I can manage but I'm having problems with constructing the actual function to check it.

Thanks a ton

Comment: This sounds a bit like "please write my code for me."  If you show your work, and specifically where the problem is, you may get a better response.  If you have questions about algorithms to detect if a number is prime, the oldest and most well-known one is The Sieve of Eratosthenes.  You may start there.

Comment: I love coding and I hate to ask without finding on my own but I got seriously stuck on this one without having any idea on how to proceed. I've never asked anybody to "write my code for me". All I needed was some tips like yours to help me out. I'll make it clear next time. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Program Primechk; 
Var 
Num                     :       Integer; 
checker,count,adder     :       ShortInt; 
Begin 
 Write('Enter one number : '); 
 Readln(Num); 
 adder := 0; 
 For count := 1 to 10 do 
   begin 
     checker := num mod count; 
     if checker = 0 then 
     adder := adder + 1 
   end; 
 if (num <= 10) and (adder > 2) then 
    Writeln(num, ' is not a prime number') 
 else 
     if (num > 10) and (adder > 1) then 
        Writeln(num, ' is not a prime number') 
     else 
         Writeln(num,' is a prime number'); 
end.
```

You can use it as a base and modifie it to your needs.
Simple googleing :]

Comment: Yup, rewrote it as function and it seems to work. Had to add if statement to exclude if num is equal or less than 1. Here's the final function. function isprime(num:integer) :boolean;
var
checker,count,adder:ShortInt;
begin
 adder := 0;
 for count := 1 to 10 do
   begin
     checker := num mod count;
     if checker = 0 then
     adder := adder + 1
   end;
 if (num <= 10) and (adder > 2) then
    isprime := false
 else
     if (num > 10) and (adder > 1) then
        isprime := false
     else if num <= 1 then
        isprime := false
     else
         isprime := true
end;